Functional derivative of a function with nested integrals
I'm trying to solve a calculus of variations problem to find the cross-sectional area of a bar as a function of its length, which minimises its volume but has some fixed displacement at the free end. I've derived that for a bar with area $A(x)$ and elastic modulus $E$, with a fixed end at $x=0$ and a free end at $x=L$ with a force $F_{end}$, the displacement anywhere in the bar is given by:
$$
u(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{F_{end}}{A\left(L\right)E}e^{\int_{0}^{L}\frac{A'\left(\xi\right)}{A\left(\xi\right)}\ d\xi-\int_{0}^{\zeta\ }\frac{A'\left(\xi\right)}{A\left(\xi\right)}\ d\xi}d\zeta
$$
From this, $u_{max}$ can simply be found by substituting $x=L$. I then have my functional defined as:
$$
J(A, A')=\int_{0}^{L}A(\zeta)+\lambda\frac{F_{end}}{A\left(L\right)E}e^{\int_{0}^{L}\frac{A'\left(\xi\right)}{A\left(\xi\right)}\ d\xi-\int_{0}^{\zeta\ }\frac{A'\left(\xi\right)}{A\left(\xi\right)}\ d\xi}d\zeta
$$
Where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier for the constraint. At this point I'm stuck, as I'm not sure how to calculate the functional derivative of $J$ with respect to $A$ and $A'$. Specifically I'm not sure how to approach the nested integrals. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

You can simplify a lot the exponential term:
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\int_0^L\frac{A'(\xi)}{A(\xi)},d\xi-\int_0^{\zeta}\frac{A'(\xi)}{A(\xi)},d\xi\right)
&=\exp\left(\int_{\zeta}^L\frac{A'(\xi)}{A(\xi)},d\xi\right) \
&=\exp\left(\ln A(L)-\ln A(\zeta)\right) \
&=\frac{A(L)}{A(\zeta)}.
\end{align}
